# Using the Google Cloud Storage S3 Migration Interface with requestor pays bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, migration

Background:

Both Amazon and Google support some version of the "Requestor Pays" bucket. In this paradigm, ingress/egress charges are paid by the requestor of the data movement rather than by the owner of the bucket. Here are some command line examples:

AWS
aws s3 sync --request-payer requester s3://requestor_pays_bucket .

GCS
gsutil -u requestor_pays_account cp gs://requestor_pays_bucket/file1 .

In both cases all that is required at the rest level is to include a new header. For AWS this is documented at

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html

The GCS documentation is at

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#access-requester-pays-xml

In my case, I have an existing piece of software that uses the S3 protocol. Using the GCS S3 migration interface (which IIUC) is essentially Googles implementation of the S3 Rest Interface, I can get my piece of software to perform many file operations such as get, put, list and delete to work with both S3 and GCS.  But I am not sure whether or not the GCS implementation of S3 includes the requestor pay functionality. If you look at the command line examples above, you will notice that there is a difference in the way the command like tools support this, in that for gsutil you have to actually specify a paying user account, while for aws you simply state that the requestor is paying.

Is there a list somewhere of which AWS headers are supported by GCS?

Any help appreciated
Howard

Comment: Don't know if I can help with the list you asked, but you can set on by default [that the requestor pays](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/requesterpays).

Comment: Are you trying to use the S3 API interface to enable requestor pays, or just access files that are set requestor pays. In either case, what have you tried? Try to simplify your question - you are providing lots of details that are confusing (to me) what you are trying to ask. Also, always ask your question first and the provide the details.

Comment: I'm trying to access files that have been set to requestor pays using the S3 interface,  It doesn't work, which isn't surprising since I don't know how to use the S3 interface to mimic the -u flag in the command above.